# Group Cassandra Rows Then Write As Parquet File Using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I need to write Cassandra Partitions as parquet file. Since I cannot share and use sparkSession in foreach function. Firstly, I call collect method to collect all data in driver program then I write parquet file to HDFS, as below.

Thanks to this link https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/16_partitioning.md

I am able to get my partitioned rows. I want to write partitioned rows into seperated parquet file, whenever a partition is read from cassandra table. I also tried sparkSQLContext that method writes task results as temporary. I think, after all the tasks are done. I will see parquet files.

Is there any convenient method for this?

```
val keyedTable : CassandraTableScanRDD[(Tuple2[Int, Date], MyCassandraTable)] = getTableAsKeyed()

keyedTable.groupByKey
      .collect
      .foreach(f => {
        import sparkSession.implicits._
        val items = f._2.toList
        val key = f._1
        val baseHDFS = "hdfs://mycluster/parquet_test/"
        val ds = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataset(items)

    ds.write
      .option("compression", "gzip")
      .parquet(baseHDFS + key._1 + "/" + key._2)

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Spark SQL everywhere & use built-in functionality of the Parquet to write data by partitions, instead of creating a directory hierarchy yourself?

Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("table", "keyspace").load()

data.write
      .option("compression", "gzip")
      .partitionBy("col1", "col2")
      .parquet(baseHDFS)
```

In this case, it will create a separate directory for every value of `col` & `col2` as nested directories, with name like this: `${column}=${value}`. Then when you read, you may force to read only specific value.

Comment: I tried this method. Spark creates 625294 tasks. But using this method, to see parquet file when a task is completed, I have to wait all the tasks are completed. When a task is completed, I see that the parquet file is written under _temporary folder in hdfs like this /parquet_test/test1/_temporary/0/task_20191226184506_0000_m_000000/col1=val1/col2=val2/part-00000-05cd29e7-af12-4ae8-bbbf-37ba1b961054.c000.gz.parquet Instead of /parquet_test/test1/col1=val1/col2=val2/part-00000-05cd29e7-af12-4ae8-bbbf-37ba1b961054.c000.gz.parquet. @Alex Ott

Comment: I have nearly 20TB Cassandra data. I dont know what is gonna happen, all data goes under _temporary folder in HDFS.  @Alex Ott

Comment: Files will be moved to the actual folder after job finishes

Comment: according to my calcution, this method takes couple of days. my second point is, If I am able to read parquet files that is created by single task, It would be good to read those files immediately.

Comment: If you are going to send all data via driver, then you are limiting your parallelism....

Comment: I am aware of those problems that’s why I asked the question. Maybe someone lead me custom solution :)